# PostgreSQL: Grouping by date and grabbing information prior to that date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am writing a query that determines the number of customers holding shares in a certain fund grouped by each day transactions happened on that fund.

So my transactions table is:

```
CREATE TABLE trans(
transID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
sin CHAR(9) REFERENCES customer(sin) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
fundID INT REFERENCES fund(fundID) NOT NULL,
transDate DATE,
shares INT,
FOREIGN KEY (fundID) REFERENCES fund(fundID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here's my query:

```
   select f.transdate, count (f.sin) 
   from (select t1.transdate, t1.sin, sum(t2.shares) 
          from fund f natural join trans t1 natural join trans t2 
          where f.fundname='Energy' 
          and t1.sin = t2.sin 
          and t2.transdate <= t1.transdate 
          group by t1.transdate, t1.sin 
          having sum(t2.shares) > 0)as f group by f.transdate 
          order by f.transdate;
```

This returns total customers holding shares on that day. However, I also want to add customers who were holding shares in the same fund all the days before.

So lets say, if I add the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO trans VALUES (DEFAULT, '1', '3', '2011-10-10', 400);
INSERT INTO trans VALUES (DEFAULT, '3', '3', '2011-10-11', 324);
INSERT INTO trans VALUES (DEFAULT, '5', '3', '2011-10-17', 201);
INSERT INTO trans VALUES (DEFAULT, '8', '3', '2011-10-17', 472);
```

So the query I stated would return this:

```
 transdate  | count 
------------+-------
 2011-10-10 |     1
 2011-10-11 |     1
 2011-10-17 |     2
```

However, I would like it to be like this:

```
 transdate  | count 
------------+-------
 2011-10-10 |     1
 2011-10-11 |     2
 2011-10-17 |     4
```

As you can see, at the end of 2011-10-11, a total of 2 people were holding shares in that fund and so on.

Any help?

Comment: Have you considered creating `Aggregate Tables`?  These would be tables prepopulated with by-day, by-month, by-whatever is the most common queries on your site.

Comment: Do you want to have a single transdate (e.g. the latest) but still count over all previous ones? Or do you want the count for each transdate separately for all days before a specific one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want the count for each transdate seperately and for all all the days before that for that specific fund.

Comment: @nightmare: shouldn't then a simple `WHERE transdate <= DATE '2011-11-10'` do what you want?

Comment: I updated my post... As I tried it but was not able to retrieve the result I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/tutorial-window.html). You can probably build up your query as follows:

- start with the query you have to get the date and the count
- from this result, query the date and count and add a column with the    "lag" function to get the value of the previous row. The window partition can be skipped since it should be over the entire rowset. The order by should be by the date. You now have the date, the count, and the count of the previous date (previous row).
- from this result query the date and the sum of the other two columns

It is best to just experiment with this a bit. Oracle refers to the Window functions as "Analytic Functions". Here is an [example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AnalyticFunctions.php).